# Select from bigquery based on more nested columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to filter by more nested data in bigquery and I am only able to filter with my query by one.

Basically i need this:

```
SELECT item_id FROM table WHERE item_id IS NOT NULL AND page_id = '23784'
```

Is such thing possible?

I have data in bigquery like below, page_id doesn't have to exist:

```
| row | date | event      | params.key    | params.value |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1   | 2018 | screenShow | item_id       | 1            |
                          | page_id       | 23784        |
                          | irrelevant_id | 5            |
| 2   | 2018 | screenShow | item_id       | 2            |
                          | irrelevant_id | 7            |
```

My query is:

```
SELECT param.value
FROM `table`,
UNNEST(params) AS param
WHERE
    event = 'screenShow'
    AND param.key = 'item_id'
```

but this obviously works only for one key and i don't know how to add the page_id part.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you want returned?

Comment: All item_ids where item_id is not null and page_id is 23784

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All item_ids where item_id is not null and page_id is 23784

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(params) param WHERE key = 'item_id') item_id
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(1) 
  FROM UNNEST(params) param 
  WHERE param = ('page_id', 23784)
  OR key = 'item_id'
  ) = 2
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 2018 dt, 'screenShow' event, 
    [STRUCT<key STRING, value INT64>('item_id', 1), ('page_id', 23784), ('irrelevant_id', 5)] params UNION ALL
  SELECT 2018 dt, 'screenShow' event, 
    [STRUCT<key STRING, value INT64>('item_id', 2), ('irrelevant_id', 7)] params UNION ALL
  SELECT 2018 dt, 'screenShow' event, 
    [STRUCT<key STRING, value INT64>('item_id2', 1), ('page_id', 23784), ('irrelevant_id', 5)] params 
)
SELECT 
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(params) param WHERE key = 'item_id') item_id
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(1) 
  FROM UNNEST(params) param 
  WHERE param = ('page_id', 23784)
  OR key = 'item_id'
  ) = 2
```

with result

```
Row item_id  
1   1
```

Obviously, if instead just list of item_id's you need whole row - you just use SELECT * as in below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(1) 
  FROM UNNEST(params) param 
  WHERE param = ('page_id', 23784)
  OR key = 'item_id'
  ) = 2
```

in this case you will get

```
| row | date | event      | params.key    | params.value |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1   | 2018 | screenShow | item_id       | 1            |
                          | page_id       | 23784        |
                          | irrelevant_id | 5            |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(params) AS x WHERE x.key = 'item_id') AS item_id
FROM
  `your_dataset.your_table`
WHERE
  EXISTS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    UNNEST(params) AS x
  JOIN
    UNNEST (params) AS y
  WHERE
    x.key = 'item_id'
    AND x.value IS NOT NULL
    AND y.key = 'page_id'
    AND y.value=23784)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from unnest(params) p where p.key = 'item_id' and p.value is not null) and
      exists (select 1 from unnest(params) p where p.key = 'page_id' and p.value = 23784);
```